# Sitecore: Saving images in media library from url

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

To download and save an image in media library I am using following code. I can see an item is created in media library but it has no media.

```cs
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData("https://myurl/images?id="+12345);
    Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
    var options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
    {
        FileBased = false,
        OverwriteExisting = true,
        Versioned = true,
        IncludeExtensionInItemName = true,
        Destination = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(Settings.GetSetting("ProfilePicturesFolderItemId")).Paths.Path + "/" + "12345",
        Database = Factory.GetDatabase("master"),
        AlternateText = userProfileItem.Name
    };


    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        var creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
        creator.CreateFromStream(memoryStream, v1ImageId, options);
    }
}
```

In the Media folder i can see an item with name, "12345" but there is no media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember, when you pass the `Destination` in options, it has to contain the new name of the item and it should be the same as the second argument in `CreateFromStream` method call just without extension:

```cs
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string filename = "SOMEFILENAME";
    string extension = ".png"; // or whatever is the extension

    byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(imageUrl);
    Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
    var options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
    {
        FileBased = false,
        OverwriteExisting = true,
        Versioned = true,
        IncludeExtensionInItemName = true,
        Destination = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(Settings.GetSetting("ProfilePicturesFolderItemId")).Paths.Path + "/" + filename,
        Database = Factory.GetDatabase("master"),
        AlternateText = userProfileItem.Name
    };


    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        var creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
        creator.CreateFromStream(memoryStream, filename + extension, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error when i tried to give extension. This code `creator.CreateFromStream(memoryStream, filename + extension, options);`  generates the error: `Parameter is not valid. `. If I remove the extenion then error is also gone.

Comment: And what is your filename and extension?

Comment: The image is .jpg and filename is 12345. I have not used your code as it is,  I modified it accordingly. I am testing it so i have the file name as 21345.

Comment: I think the problem is could be I don't have anthing in the stream. `Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);`. Do you have any idea if the  code to read image from url is right or not ?

Comment: I tested the code I pasted. It worked for me. I can confirm that it created an item called `SOMEFILENAME` in media library and that it contained a proper image downloaded from web. Yeah, there is a possibility that you cannot download an image from the location you're using, but there is no way anyone here can help you with this if you don't provide the exact url you're using.